# TypeScript how to create a generic type alias for a generic function?

Tags: typescript, generics

Given a typed generic function, I want to create a generic alias for that function, but it seems I can't. In other words, this doesn't work:

```
// foo.tsx
function foo<T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg
}

type FooT = typeof foo  // works, but alias isn't generic: <T>(arg: T) => T
type FooParametersT = Parameters<typeof foo>  // sure: [unknown]
type FooReturnT = ReturnType<typeof foo>  // no problem: unknown

type GFooT<T,> = typeof foo<T,>  // yikes
type GFooParametersT<T,> = Parameters<typeof foo<T,>>  // nope
type GFooReturnT<T,> = ReturnType<typeof foo<T,>>  // fails
```

What I'm really trying to do is grab the type of a function in someone else's library and then build an interface around it. For example:

```
import { useState } from "react"

type UseStateFnT<T,> = typeof useState<T>
const wrapUseState: (toWrap: UseStateFnT<T,>) => UseStateFnT<T,> = …
```

Is this possible without recreating [the complex typed function signature](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/22ed0c7dd49cb781a2ebc67cf2b2c2fd752c63bd/types/react/index.d.ts#L901-L915) myself?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

UPDATE FOR TS4.7+

Hello again!  TypeScript 4.7 will introduce *instantiation expressions* as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47607](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607), which will allow you to directly specify the type parameters for a generic function without actually calling the function, so there's no longer a need to abuse classes the way shown in the rest of the answer.  Here it is:

```
type GFooT<T,> = typeof foo<T>  // (arg: T) => T
type GFooParametersT<T,> = Parameters<typeof foo<T>>  // [arg: T]
type GFooReturnT<T,> = ReturnType<typeof foo<T>>  // T
```

That's almost the same as the syntax in the question except that trailing commas are not supported after type arguments (but they *are* supported after type parameter declarations).  Hooray!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.0-dev.20220302#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACgIYBOA5gFyIYCUZGiA3gLABQiiBAplCAUoUUwL5MmUAJ4AHNogBiqGgF5EoiXGDJULAPQbEAdzgEA1gGcANIgBGIKIjwAbGHiOIYRsAHJrRNmDYEYEMkxcXmoKRDkscmFxSRk4AAVCPABbDl8jeUREghS0giM0JTYVNThIxC1EIy42MgBtEMRwAzA4HTAAXWiJaVQAJQ4uMEyBzm4MGMKYkpQyzW1WxDECOHNbNmSyZtb2oUYixABxOIxME0iFIpnUIPnEfGJQ8MiMbslj1GzcqHTTjHPwlkkqkfvkpspVLMguVKg1HuQuvsYkc4qMhn8AQo0eNJldITdsDDtK9GEwgA)

---

PREVIOUS ANSWER FOR TS4.6-

There are two different flavors of generics in TypeScript: generic *functions*, and generic *types*... and it looks like you want the compiler to transform one into the other for you, which isn't directly supported.

---

To be clear:

Generic *types* have type parameters that need to be specified before you can use them as a specific type.  For example:

```
type GenType<T> = (x: T) => T[];
declare const oops: GenType; // error
declare const genT: GenType<string>; // okay
const strArr = genT("hello"); // string[];
const numArr = genT(123); // error!
```

Here, `GenType` is a generic type.  You need to specify the type parameter to use it as the type of a value, and then the resulting type is no longer generic.  The `genT` function takes a `string` and returns a `string[]`.  It cannot be used as a function that takes a `number` and returns a `number[]`.

---

Generic *functions*, on the other hand, have a specific type that can act like any possible substitution of its type parameters.  The value of a generic function type is still generic when you use it.  The type parameter is attached to the call signature:

```
type GenFunc = <T>(x: T) => T[];
declare const genF: GenFunc;
const strArr = genF("hello"); // strArr: string[];
const numArr = genF(123); // numArr: number[];
```

Here, `GenFunc` is a specific type referring to a generic function.  The `genF` function is still generic when it is called.

Generic functions (including generic constructor functions) can be thought of as [generic values](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574), as opposed to generic types.

---

These two flavors of generics are related to each other but the TypeScript type system isn't expressive enough to talk about how they are related.  In some other language, you might be able to define one in terms of the other like

```
type GenFunc = forall T, GenType<T>; // not TS, error
```

or

```
type GenType<T> = instantiate GenFunc with T; // not TS, error
```

but in TypeScript you can't.  Maybe if we ever get *higher kinded types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)... but not now.  So it is not directly possible to turn `GenFunc` into `GenType` programmatically in the type system.

---

There are evil awful ways to coerce the compiler to calculate `GenType` in terms of `GenFunc`.  The way I know of makes use of generic class property initialization and some [higher order type inference for generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) introduced in TypeScript 3.4.  I'm making the compiler think it's calculating values when I don't actually have any, and then getting the type of one of these pretend values:

```
class GenTypeMaker<T> {
    getGenType!: <A extends any[], R>(cb: (...a: A) => R) => () => (...a: A) => R;
    genType = this.getGenType(null! as GenFunc)<T>()
}
type GenType2<T> = GenTypeMaker<T>['genType']
// type GenType2<T> = (x: T) => T[]
```

You can verify that `GenType2<T>` is the same type as `GenType<T>`, and if you change `GenFunc` into any generic function with one type parameter, `GenType2<T>` will change accordingly.

But I don't know I'd want to recommend anyone actually use this method.  And it doesn't really scale or compose; if you have an object full of generic functions in one type parameter and you want to transform it to an object full of specific functions with a specified type parameter, there's no way to use this method to get it from the type system without doing it once for each object property.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/AQKALgngDgpsDiMB2AVaMA8KB8wC8wAFAB4BcwKAlPrigNoC6A3CEgIYC2MAzlGwMZxEqYAG8QwScAAmMfgBs2AJzj8A9km5hgatVG7lhaWE2AB6M8BhKlapRKmyFy1Rq3AA5shSHv6DFpKAJZIHtimFjoA1mwQDpLqmtqBAII2+J7ehABEABYw8vJq2ZQRloEhHowsUsCJ7kgArhxpShleqIQAjABMAMyl5pbWtkoAhCAAviDg6AjIAGKNSPwZWNgk5FQ0FNWsnDx8gvNIC2LxMnKKKnVu2h0LvqfL-DVS9clgSq3tizn5hWKg0iqRs5AqoT2tQ+wCaLXSBAe3X6wMscNa5DhACNrHtpvsuLwBHAACIqTgAGTYoUabC851qkFgJyWKwyADM7GxChQADQnYyYHBlWFqbQoADK-JGdguTKEflg6wyIS01LAQTYYAVzzZAHcgmBchQRUgxRQpVYbLL8c5uNwBegALJsKLWZXiWpeMBGdBjcgYFJWYjapDSB3UiCMfkAJQ2-Cx5EIADpU2xyClqHhcDGs7hCHmiKnk+ngJmdjG3pIOoKMkagtxk97fbBCE1CmNgGwHcJWfxKOsC1NZsyWzAesqCGOXW6lOs6AByGvoBcMECReWO2ATnAZTYUQv0NdAA)

Comment: I think I had to read this three times to start to grok it, but that's a reflection of my ignorance of Typescript nuances, not your response, which was thorough and well-written. Thanks for that! I'm accepting this in the hopes that, some future comment or response will be of the, "This is now possible as of TypeScript <X>.<Y> … ," variety that seems to commonplace among many TypeScript questions here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is it possible to make that class only exist at the type level? using `declare` doesn't seem to work. I found a use case where I might be able to use this procedurally, but if I must create a class at runtime it is not worth it.

Comment: @posita hey guess what! 

Comment: @geoffrey I think the TS4.7+ solution I edited in is your best bet here; I don't think the original answer will work without at least some runtime code being emitted.

Comment: it is fantastic news! I think for now I'll go with the original answer+ a babel plug-in to clean up the emitted JS as it won't be a breaking change to adopt the new syntax when TS4.7 lands

Comment: Woohoo! Nice! (Apologies for not responding earlier. I was having trouble commenting for some reason.)