# How do I pass a generic value type accessed through an index in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I"m trying to pass a generic value to a type accessed through an index, but I'm running into a syntax error.

I've got a function type signature named `onCreateNode` defined on an interface named `GatsbyNode`:

```
interface GatsbyNode {
  ...
  onCreateNode?<TNode extends object = {}>(
    args: CreateNodeArgs<TNode>,
    options?: PluginOptions,
    callback?: PluginCallback
  ): void
  ...
```

I've now created a function that is also named `onCreateNode` and I want to assign it the type of `GatsbyNode['onCreateNode']` while passing a value to the `TNode` generic:

```
export const onCreateNode: GatsbyNode['onCreateNode']<AGenericTypeIWantToPassIn> = ...
```

However, I get a syntax error at the first angle bracket (`<`) telling me that this is not valid TypeScript.

Comment: I think the error is because your assigning {} to object, which you cant do in an interface (I believe - correct me if I'm wrong someone)

Comment: @MaxCarroll I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: `onCreateNode?<TNode extends object = {}` this line here is causing the error because of the default assignment ` = {} ` you should be able to remove the `= {} ` and that will be one less error. Default assignment is possible in classes, but not interfaces or types in TypeScript

Comment: The ` onCreateNode?<TNode extends object = {}>` definition comes from a library. Also, i'm not sure removing the `= {}` would help since the purpose of `= {}` is to use an empty object as the value of the generic if one is not provided. The `extends object` part of the generic is to ensure that the value used for the generic is an object (i.e. you can't pass a string in as the value for the generic).

Comment: Well its just I don't think that that's possible in TypeScript, my compiler says also, I'm looking in the documentation for evidence of having a default assignment for a generic type in an interface but haven't found anything yet, will update if I find anything

Comment: Yes, it's valid TypeScript. Check this out: https://repl.it/@robertcoopercod/default-generic-values#index.ts

Comment: So it is. Thanks for sharing that, there seems to be no obvious examples of anything like this in the docs I was looking at

Comment: I've added to your fiddle does this help at all ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217278/discussion-between-robert-cooper-and-max-carroll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to convert a *generic function* type to a *generic type* referring to a function.  These are two fundamentally different sorts of generics, and although they are related, the compiler doesn't really give you a direct mechanism to convert between them.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724646/2887218) for a fuller explanation; this question is essentially asking for what the other question is asking for.

Anyway, the most straightforward way for you to proceed is to just rewrite the type definition in the desired form yourself:

```
type GatsbyNodeSpecific<T extends object = {}> = {
  onCreateNode?(args: CreateNodeArgs<T>, options?: PluginOptions, callback?: PluginCallback): void;
}

export const onCreateNode: GatsbyNodeSpecific<AGenericTypeIWantToPassIn>['onCreateNode'] = null!
```

This will definitely work, but is potentially tedious and possibly error-prone if the upstream definition of `GatsbyNode` changes.

---

In the other answer, I show a hacky method to convince the compiler to take a generic function type and convert it to a generic type.  For your case it would look like this:

```
class GenTypeMaker<T extends object = {}> {
  getGatsbyNodeSpecific!: <A extends any[], R>(cb: (...a: A) => R) => () => (...a: A) => R;
  gatsbyNodeSpecific = this.getGatsbyNodeSpecific!(
    null! as NonNullable<GatsbyNode["onCreateNode"]>)<T>()
}
type OnCreateGatsbyNodeSpecific<T extends object> = 
  GenTypeMaker<T>['gatsbyNodeSpecific'] | undefined;
```

And then you can use this new type like this:

```
export const onCreateNode2: OnCreateGatsbyNodeSpecific<AGenericTypeIWantToPassIn> = onCreateNode;
```

This is the same type as before.  But I doubt anyone reviewing the code above with a phantom `class` would be happy with it, and the straightforward-if-redundant method of rewriting the definition manually is probably the better way to go.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Hm1BpNEXC0UCLKkCBgH1+xnM4MIPPsShETkVJsaKHJROZ6YAJU6CGxyDcADot2iiH5WvRF3uWvQ3EeT1uNzuz8hF8Zu3T-YRAyy2QgUWAABbAcgbnt9h+DkGr55m4uaSHmWgaHgIDYNI9hwA4ZKUP29IFImABEaaKhA6GZrQfg0J0fgvII1IoPIICDJAKGPhAz7Dg2U5VDUfJtoKwptOWlYQDWdZQIRKakABAZDq+WbIAAPsg0hVBAbL-Pgxh2swDpOnsrrZJRCqeoQABM7AUVREA0YBL4huW4bcVG0KwqWCYolhOkQMYQA)

Comment: You sir, are a TypeScript wizard. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In TypeScript it isn't possible to apply type arguments to indexed access types. That's by design because it would require extending the grammar to support multiple sets of type arguments for generic types with generic methods, such as

```
type Foo<T> = <U>(t: T, u: U) => [T, U];
```

Thus the following won't work:

```
class Echo {
  echo = <T>(a: T): T => a;
}
type EchoNumFunc = Echo["echo"]<number>; // Does not work
```

TypeScript 4.7 introduced [instantiation expressions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607) which provide the ability to specify type arguments for generic functions or generic constructors without actually calling them:

```
function makeBox<T>(value: T) {
    return { value };
};
const makeStringBox = makeBox<string>;  // (value: string) => { value: string }
const stringBox = makeStringBox('abc');  // { value: string }
```

Exploiting the `declare` keyword allows you to take advantage of the previously mentioned feature to workaround the issue in the following way:

```
class Echo {
  echo = <T>(a: T): T => a;
}
declare const echo: Echo["echo"];
type EchoNumFunc = typeof echo<number>; // Works
```