# Generic types and function definitions - "cannot find name T"

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to understand how to define functions that accept type arguments. Intuitively, I would expect this to work (ignore the code, it's fake):

```js
type UseListStateType<T> = (
  initialState: T[] | null
) => [
  T[], // The items currently in the list
  (itemToToggle: T) => void // Function to add/remove an item from the list.
];

const myFunction: UseListStateType<T> = (initialState) => {
    const items = initialState || [];

    const toggleItem = (item:any) => {
        if (items.indexOf(item) === -1) {
            items.push(item);
        } else {
            items.splice(items.indexOf(item), 1);
        }
    }

    return [items, toggleItem]
}
```

([link to typescript playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhAMgSzsAysAhsCAVcCAHjwD4oBeKACgFgAoKKZAO2WGSwBtMcIAuKHgDaAXSgAfKCwCuXLgwCUlcsIZMRogDRQA9LqEALaOwgBbOFADGMgE62ILYFxDMWUYMahdUwdTVMzPAB7EIBzMK4BIWUKcgA3YOQAEz0DADEZFisOYPdgYKgsZOTdBzNg+Ogsd0CoADNbYLMPLx80ADoGUQBuBgYrPLQoMxBM7NyWQXgkX15cAkgScipqVnZOHmxcWPIAb38mQZZhwMsqdY5ueegJKTE++kPrIeAPYIiogElcFtXA-g1EC7KAHRhMCFMZD1AK-OAdVjJCAADwA8vU1r9YhQqABaACMyjBkJJELOHTAMjghkx5kUj1JTAAvlAIFwEKDnozmHCOnAwD4rBBaRYESwkWiMYFFDpCQzGUznoqnuCmA5gHZ3MIzjoCp8ID9zKIGMqBq8oNq4bqPpEDb9xFRRuMcsg8tRZPJFP16MdhsJQJBkoaLNb9YsIEH7ZQRmMsi68kQ0LZWGFSO65FxFEA))

However when we use the type `<T>` on the line declaring `myFunction` we get the error "Cannot find name `T`".

What *does* work, is if we move the type after the `=`:

```js
type UseListStateType = <T>(
  initialState: T[] | null
) => [
  T[], // The items currently in the list
  (itemToToggle: T) => void // Function to add/remove an item from the list.
];

// This works as expected
const myFunction: UseListStateType = (initialState) => {
    const items = initialState || [];

    const toggleItem = (item:any) => {
        if (items.indexOf(item) === -1) {
            items.push(item);
        } else {
            items.splice(items.indexOf(item), 1);
        }
    }

    return [items, toggleItem]
}

const [items, toggleItem] = myFunction(null)

const [typedItems, toggleTypedItem] = myFunction<string>(null)
```

But the type definition above looks very strange to me, and all examples I can find would put the type on the left as per the first example. Can someone explain to me the difference, and let me know if there is any alternative?

Comment: You cannot **declare** a generic type (your `T`) in the left side of an assignment. Your second version is correct.

Comment: @known-as-bmf - elsewhere I have done something like: `type ResourcesState<T> = { items: T[] };` which works when I use `const myState: ResourcesState<string> = { items: ['test'] };` - I'm sure there is a difference but I can't quite get it!

Comment: The difference is that with `type` you declare a type (left generic declaration allowed) and with `myFunction` you declare a value (no left generic declaration).

Comment: Maybe using `function` would be easier to understand: `function myFunction<T>(initialState: T[] | null): [T[], (itemToToggle: T) => void]` .. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFzXmAPAFQD4AKGMGWAQwBsBlKSqAUwC5F8BtAXUQB9EwIatQCUbDu24AaRKWbJ8cRQHNl1VuxGIAvIUQA3ODAAmPAN4BYAFCJbiCAgDOURBSbJHO1+Sp0GzPn5uAG5razt7JxcoOFV1AEl5Lzl3FkowVC1dREsbCLsYYFk3DwA6MmMmAA8AeWAU5CztbUQAWgBGLVz8ntd5R1KABxBHAAsGkVC8noBfRCZqRyYc8N6IkoHHQeoYCCYGgYrquomZTqm1mdXbK6trxAAnJigQB6QODZkYuKZE9y5rLdrA4wM5EB9+l9YmpfvIeC00JhILAEMRBMIRGErCCwRwoKhBkxjH8PFCfvgCUSSfCUBgsCi8M4HmRlCR0aIgA

Comment: Does the first half of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724646/2887218) answer your question?

Comment: @known-as-bmf - Ok, I think I get it - if the type argument is on the left when the type is defined, that argument is _required_ to use the type. If It's on the right, any value which has the type assigned to it will accept a type argument?

Comment: @jcalz yes! Thank you. That's exactly what I needed.