# Make a generic type concrete in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a following function:

```
function addRelay<T>(msg: T): SomeGeneric<T> {
  return {msg: msg, relay: true};
}
```

I need to pass this function to another function:

```
higherOrder(addRelay);
```

this works fine. However, I would like to make the generic type concrete before passing the function (in the most concise way). The code works fine when I do the following:

```
higherOrder((x: {concreteType: number}) => addRelay(x));
```

However, when I do:

```
higherOrder(addRelay<{concreteType: number}>)
```

I get:
`Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.`. How do I concretize a given function without explicitly constructing a lambda function around it?

Comment: can you show your higherOrder function definition?

Comment: because this works: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgcWQO2QJwJbAB4AVAPmgG8AoSgX2oDMBXDYAF13g2jABMeAlZOACexEgApEEAOYAuaEQCU8hCnRY8hUhUrRo2ZK0bYu5KXOjmANPqFhh81tkbIaAbloNmbDlwAWuNJ+OADy2Dw4YuJMLPKSMvJK0AC8ZKpomDj4YooUdJQBQaHhOOK8AnbCim5AA)

Comment: You need type ```higherOrder``` with generic, like ```higherOrder<T>((msg: T) => SomeGeneric<T>)```

Comment: the higher-level function is actually [createAction](https://ngrx.io/api/store/createAction) (I'm passing `addRelay` as it's second argument). But even in the example that @PoulKruijt provided, when I do `higherOrder(addRelay<number>);`, trying to make `T` concrete, I get the same error as above.

Comment: Or you could use a factory method, like so ```function addRelayFactory<T>(func: (msg: T) => SomeGeneric<T>)  { return (msg: T) => func(msg); }```

Comment: TypeScript lacks a way to ask for generics to be specified this way (I have an answer to a similar question).  You can do this: `const concretizeAddRelay = <T>(): (msg: T) => SomeGeneric<T> => addRelay; const addRelayConcrete = concretizeAddRelay<{concreteType: number}>();` or just `const addRelayConcrete: (msg: { concreteType: number }) => SomeGeneric<{ concreteType: number }> = addRelay;`, but you're going to be doing either some extra runtime work or extra type system work.  Is that better than a lambda?  Not sure.  Let me know if you want me to expand to an answer.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720954/typescript-how-to-create-a-generic-type-alias-for-a-generic-function) is a near duplicate; if not the question, then the underlying issue

Comment: thanks @jcalz. Your first suggestion is basically what I was looking for: I assume this works in the compilation time?

Comment: Well, if you use the first suggestion then you get at runtime: `const concretizeAddRelay = () => addRelay; const addRelayConcrete = concretizeAddRelay()` which seems like a bunch of weird no-ops just to give you `addRelayConcrete` that you can use in place of `addRelay`.  The second suggestion is just `const addRelayConcrete = addRelay` which is less roundabout but still is visible.  You could also write `higherOrder(addRelay as (msg: { concreteType: number }) => SomeGeneric<{ concreteType: number }>)` which has no runtime impact but is a little less type safe.

Comment: When I get a chance I'll flesh this out into an answer...