# How to create function in TypeScript based on another, but with fixed some template parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, types

Is there a easy way to fix some template parameter of function in TypeScript.
For example:

```
const selectFromObj = <T, S>(obj: T, selector: (obj: T) => S): S =>  selector(obj) // some function from external library

type SpecificType = {a: string, b: number}
const selectFromSpecificObj: <S>(obj: SpecificType, selector: (s: SpecificType) => S) => S = selectFromObj

// Can last two lines be replaced with something like line below? 
// Just to fix T to {a: string, b: number}
// const selectFromSpecificObj: <S>(typeof selectFromObj<{a: string, b: number}, S>) = selectFromObj
```

Comment: This feels like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720954/typescript-how-to-create-a-generic-type-alias-for-a-generic-function).  TypeScript doesn't have direct support for the higher order type juggling needed to turn a generic function type into a specific function type; you can only specify the type parameter when you *call* the function.

Comment: Can you provide an example of when you would need to fix the type parameter? Via subtyping, the generalized form should work everywhere you want your narrowed type.

Comment: @jcalz I think it's doable. Is there something that I'm misunderstanding in my answer?

Comment: It's not that you couldn't manually write a type like `ApplySelectorFunc<SpecificType>`, but that's just an intermediate manually-crafted type that applies to `selectFromSpecificObj` only.  The question as I see it is this: given a generic function type like `<T, U>(...)=>...` can you *programmatically* substitute specific types for `T` and `U` in the *type* of the function?  Where you can take `typeof selectFromObj` as an opaque thing and plug in `T` and `U`.  The answer to that is "unfortunately not".

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the explanation.  Based on the way that the question is worded I assume that they are ok with setting the type manually.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. We define a type that describes the `selectFromObj` function where the object type `T` is fixed, but the return type `S` depends on the arguments that it is called with.

```
type ApplySelectorFunc<T> = <S>(obj: T, selector: (obj: T) => S) => S;
```

Then we can create renamed aliases of `selectFromObj` which can only accept objects of a known type once we assign the type `ApplySelectorFunc` to them with a specific value for `T`

```
type SpecificType = {a: string, b: number}

const selectFromSpecificObj: ApplySelectorFunc<SpecificType> = selectFromObj;

const good = selectFromSpecificObj({a: "", b: 1}, o => o.a)  // type = string
const bad = selectFromSpecificObj({a: ""}, o => o.a)  // error
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmYBsQGUIIgY2AewE4DEBXAOwwB4AVAPigF4ozkqAKbAIwCsAuKCgGigBnNJhy4erTjwoBKOjWRzaCgNwBYAFCaM2YoOBCRWfLmwBbAPKc6DflCaTuvAcPRY8E9k9nz7Mnsi%20hm5ijnIA9OFC5tAAZiRYAJa6ULGmZlAQAB7AELjEAIYIUAiJbLgFuCCamqCQ9pAYibGJGBTg0PQA3gU8%20riJxADmAmw8xIRmbHkAvtq6%20sGiJubIjc2tVk5wiChGYkSkjOstbR009K7L6Vs1Gjp6BkPY2AAmNlfG6WuYGxhbzB6PAARMDRjwAIwzATYXzYAB0BTkUEiUDqnSEwAGw3mjygbAK70u%20xWZh%20TVOAKBUFB0KgsOU9MRyNReVMuCAA)

Comment: nice! great answer! not sure if understood the question, but I liked the technique you show here