# How to explicitly type a generic function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

### Problem

I have the following generic function type:

```
type Validator<TInput, TOutput extends TInput> = (value: TInput) => Validated<TOutput>;
```

Now I want to implement this type, so I did the following:

```
const isNotNull: Validator<T | null, T> = <T>(value: T | null): Validated<T> => {
    // Implementation here
};
```

This doesn't work because `T` is used before it's defined.

I know I can infer the type of `isNotNull` but I want to **explicitly** declare it as `Validator` as a constraint. How do I do this?

---

### Context

This `Validator` type will be used as a function argument, like the following:

```
function validate<TInput, TOutput>(
    value: TInput,
    validator: Validator<TInput, TOutput>
): TOutput {}
```

*Of course in reality there is no need for this function. The real scenario is more complex, but I've stripped it down to the minimum.*

This is why `Validator` must be generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript lacks the expressiveness necessary to describe the `isNotNull` function as a type of `Validator`.  If TypeScript had arbitrary "generic values" as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574), one might be able to say something like:

```
declare const isNotNull: forall T, Validator<T | null, T>; // not valid TS, error
```

But there is no way to do this currently.  (For more info, I go on about generics in TypeScript in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720954/typescript-how-to-create-a-generic-type-alias-for-a-generic-function).)

Without the ability to do this programmatically, you will probably want to do it manually:

```
declare const isNotNull: <T>(value: T | null) => Validated<T>;
```

Luckily, though, while the compiler cannot *express* that `isNotNull` is related to `Validator`, it can *recognize* it.  So you can still pass `isNotNull` to `validate()` without problems:

```
validate(Math.random() < 0.5 ? 123 : null, isNotNull);
// function validate<number | null, number>(
//   value: number | null, validator: Validator<number | null, number>
// ): number
```

The compiler sees that `isNotNull` can be treated as a `Validator<number | null, number>`.

---

The only other way I can imagine proceeding here is to represent a generic function that *returns* `Validator<T | null, T>` when you call it with a type parameter of `T`, like this:

```
const getIsNotNull = <T>(): Validator<T | null, T> => isNotNull;
validate(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "hey" : null, getIsNotNull<"hey">());
```

This gives you the ability to say "`isNotNull` has something to do with `Validator`", but at the cost of a useless no-arg curried function.  I'd much prefer using `validate` with `isNotNull` directly.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.1.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBM7AigPAFQHxQC8UA3gFBSVQDuAFuhAG4BcUOA3GQL5lmiSxEqdAHsATlgCSAGigB5KBAAeGAHYoAzlEkFiACkaIArhFaSAlEQLxkaDNjl5OZAGZHVAY2BIRqqIdsGKVkFZTVNbTw9CioAkzNpGMoA4WBxVhtU8WD5PDJzVgVyKigxCGAjMT8Uu3EDYwhzADo6BkZOHjIAei6oFAgPBDgyqA9fDWAoJA0AORFgGaMEBFYXcUQENllM2okcKAAfKFUlhFl8dige4-n-IRQ2AGVZCDExcV5+weHoMdUJqazeaLZasXBROKmNiHY6nSyEaz3BjYC68GoMPQAWXQtCaYjg6hEAFs9JYsFAAAxNACsUAA-FAAIwAJgAzFBWCdlrJpnMFnDONc3J5vL47oEMFgTkSAEavGFcs6w2WvKLdXrJBqcowqsQK06ydFpMQZJHGqU6uV6o6K2TSq15a4FZVW3h-AEAc3KkiB-OWRCg4NJpol2X2NoNbF0BF5wNOnCNECxOLxBJQxNJgcpNPpUAARLQICA8xzYdyoF7gD6+SCEFgC0W81FzOZ2EA)