# How to "fill in" generic parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a generic typescript function like this:

```
function doThing<T>(param: T): T {
    //...
}
```

And I have a concrete interface like this:

```
interface MyType {
    x: string;
    y: number;
}
```

I want to re-export `doThing` method so that it assumes generic parameter `T` is always `MyType`. The reason is so that I can type something like:

```
doThing({
```

...and editor will auto-complete members `x` and `y` without me having to specify `T` in advance.

I know I can do something like:

```
import {doThing as _doThing} from 'some-module';
export const doThing = _doThing as (param: MyType) => MyType;
```

However, this is cumbersome and error prone. Also, `doThing` actually has a lot more members and variants than in this simplified example, so it would take a lot of copy-pasting.

Is there a way to simply "fill in" `T`, without having to copy-paste the entire original definition?

Comment: There's no `instantiate typeof doThing with T` notation (as I mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724646/2887218)) so no obvious way to do this without some redundancy.  Or, with [pure evil](https://tsplay.dev/YmpXam) you can do it, but is it worth it?  Test it out and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is allowed since [TypeScript 4.7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#instantiation-expressions).

```js
const foo: typeof doThing<MyType> = doThing
```

Edit: The line (1) should also work according to the release notes, but because of [a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50161) extra parentheses (2) are required as of TypeScript 4.8.

```js
const foo = doThing<MyType>    // (1) error
const foo = (doThing)<MyType>  // (2) ok
```

Comment: This is the solution we've been waiting for. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose we can directly use this function like this:

```
let res = doThing<MyType>({x: "something", y: 0});
```

Comment: I explicitly want to avoid specifying type parameter every time I use the function.