# TypeScript: Typing forwarded arguments to Map<K,V> constructor with known <K,V>

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I'm trying to write a function that forwards arguments to `new Map(…)`, contrived example here:

```js
function createMap(initialValues) { // Parameter 'initialValues' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  return new Map<string, string>(initialValues)
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQWQwBwAoYwZYMAbANUpDQGcBKRAbwFgAoRRdKEFJGDQB3RHnwAeelBQkA5gBpE02WDkA+YqXLVaDRpwC+QA)

**How should I type `initialValues`?**

I was hoping to do something like this, but it doesn't even seem to be valid syntax:

```js
function createMap(initialValues: ConstructorParameters<typeof Map<string, string>>[0]) {
  return new Map<string, string>(initialValues)
}
```

This does work, but doesn't seem right, I don't actually want to subclass Map:

```js
class MyMap extends Map<string, string> {} // :/

function createMap(initialValues: ConstructorParameters<typeof MyMap>[0]) {
  return new Map<string, string>(initialValues)
}
```

Changing `class` to `interface` doesn't work.

I tried playing around like this, but this doesn't work:

```js
function createMap(initialValues: ConstructorParameters<typeof Map>[0]) {
  return new Map<string, string>(initialValues) // No overload matches this call
}
```

This doesn't work:

```js
type MyMap = Map<string, string>

// 'MyMap' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
function createMap(initialValues: ConstructorParameters<typeof MyMap>[0]) {
  return new Map<string, string>(initialValues)
}
```

And nor does this:

```js
type MyMap = Map<string, string>

// Type 'MyMap' does not satisfy the constraint 'new (...args: any) => any'. Type 'Map<string, string>' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any): any'.
function createMap(initialValues: ConstructorParameters<MyMap>[0]) {
  return new Map<string, string>(initialValues)
}
```

So I think I'm missing some important pieces in my understanding of what's going on here, why do none of the things I tried work? e.g. what actually is `type MyMap = Map<K, V>`?

**Is there an alternative, type-safe way to do this so I don't have to use `ConstructorParameters<…>[0]` at all? One that doesn't involve manually copying the signature of `Map.new`?**

Comment: Without explicit support for *higher kinded types* (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)) there's no way to do this that doesn't involve some wacky hijinks like what you're doing.

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720954/typescript-how-to-create-a-generic-type-alias-for-a-generic-function) but it has a similar answer: the generics in TS aren't expressive enough at the type level to do this.  I think manually writing `Iterable<readonly [string, string]>` has got to be better than all that other stuff, unfortunately.

Comment: This is what I feared.