# Is it possible to define a generic function in terms of a generic type?

Tags: typescript, generics

I think that what I'm trying to do is impossible, but I would like to confirm it. I'm trying to combine two different concepts with generics.

Firstly, a generic function that accepts one type parameter of its own:

```
const genericFn = <T>(value: T) => {
  // value is explicitly typed as the passed-in type parameter T
};
```

And secondly, a function that is typed by some other generic function type:

```
type GenericFunction<T> = (value: T) => void;

type MySpecificType = unknown;

const myFunc: GenericFunction<MySpecificType> = (value) => {
  // value is implictly typed as MySpecificType by GenericFunction
};
```

I want to combine those two things and have a function that accepts a type parameter and passes it into a generic function type. This is not valid syntax as far as I can tell:

```
type GenericFunction<T> = (value: T) => void;

const myFunc: GenericFunction<T> = <T>(value) => {
  // value is implicitly typed as the generic type T, by GenericFunction
}
```

I guess I'm trying to use `<T>`, passing it into `<GenericFunction>`, before it has actually been defined as a parameter. So I get `Cannot find name 'T'` on that first occurrence of `<T>`

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know why this was closed as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720954/typescript-how-to-create-a-generic-type-alias-for-a-generic-function. It's not the same question. If someone thinks it is, please leave a comment or an answer explaining how, rather than just drive-by closing my question 

Comment: Well, because it is a clear as day a duplicate. jcalz is one of the top contributors on TS down here, I doubt they do anything "drive-by". It is the *answers* that make a question duplicate, not the question. You are asking how to combine a generic function signature with a generic type, which is *exactly* what the other Q&A is about.