# Objects composed of generic types in TypeScript (type recursion)

Tags: typescript, recursive-type

Given the following untyped TS:

```
const compose = (thunk: any): any => {
  const res = { ...thunk() };
  return { ...res, then: (f: any): any => compose(() => ({...res, ...f()})) };
};
```

We can use it to make composable objects:

```
const { foo, bar } = compose(() => ({foo: 1})).then(() => ({bar: 2}))
// foo: 1, bar: 2
```

But typing this in TS seems tricky, as the types are recursive.

The best I could come up with is:

```
type Compose<T> = (thunk: () => T) => T & { then: Compose<any> };

const compose2 = <T extends {}>(thunk: () => T): ReturnType<Compose<T>> => {
  const res = { ...thunk() };
  return { ...res, then: (f) => compose2(() => ({ ...res, ...f() })) };
};
```

This means that all the objects that fall out of `compose2` are of type `any`.
The end result I'd like to accomplish is something that's typed with all of the composed objects:

```
const combined = compose(() => ({foo: 1})).then(() => ({bar: 2}))
// type of combined: { foo: number } & { bar: number } & { then: … }
```

The way I see it we'd need some sort of `Fix` type that can tie the recursive knot, as the type for `then` in `Compose` needs to recurse.

Of course, there might be a way to do it if we inverted the signature of `compose` and somehow used CPS. I'm open for suggestions!

Note that a 2-ary `compose`, let's call it `combine`, is no issue:

```
const combine = <A extends {}, B extends {}>(a: () => A, b: () => B): A & B => ({...a(), ...b()});
const bar = combine(() => ({foo: 1}), () => combine(() => ({bar: 2}), () => ({baz: 3})) )
```

But it isn't particularly nice to write the statements, so I hoped to pass a closure from the resulting object so I wouldn't have to nest repeated function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for this:

```
type Compose<O extends object = {}> =
    <T extends object>(thunk: () => T) => T & O & {
        then: Compose<T & O>
    }

const compose: Compose = (thunk) => {
    const res = { ...thunk() };
    return { ...res, then: f => compose(() => ({ ...res, ...f() })) };
};
```

The return type of `then()` carries some state information you need to represent in your compose type.  If we think of `O` as "the current state object", then `Compose<O>` is a generic function which takes a `thunk` of type `() => T` for any other object type `T`, and returns a `T & O & {then: Compose<T & O>}`... that is, the new object is the intersection of `T` and `O`, and its `then()` method has `T & O` as the new state.

The fact that the implementation of `compose()` type checks is a good sign.  Let's verify that the compiler understands how calls work:

```
const { foo, bar } = compose(() => ({ foo: 1 })).then(() => ({ bar: "hello" }));

console.log(foo.toFixed(2)) // 1.00
console.log(bar.toUpperCase()); // HELLO
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAzhAPAeShAHsCAOwBMUo4AjAKwgGNgoBeKAbwF8A+JgWACgoBUdABUc+IqXLU6wDgApgACwCuhANYAuKHICUTLsL2MDUAGRRs5ln0G2oSolvhJUGUecwcbgtn1pxCFAZ-FzQnRGQ0Jm0lVTUjLmt+QX9AhgAnCDJmFigAOgLY9V0oNgBubwFM4GV0wlZ8gsyUABp7RUcoADN9KBDIiDkS421cgrzmtvGukrYdPXK+Rd4-AKCGrrg4NooAQ3TS6P7XIYTR7q2tAEZS+byHQlPeuVy99K0AIg6AG2+4D9uOgqK14qRQcG+EDyfwA5nJNnB7nAAGIAS1wEGIcgATPMoAB6fFQK55AAMpNWgQhUNhcjeSIAqmBIOkYLs0LogQSiQAJACiABkBZg+EA)

Comment: Yeah, that's fantastic, thanks! I also learned that you can specify *another generic* on the RHS of a `type` decl. That's useful, thanks. The trick with defaulting `O` to `{}` to avoid having to specify the generic on the `const` decl is also neat.

Comment: There are two "flavors" of generics in TypeScript; generic *types*, and generic *functions*.  In `Compose<O>`, the `O` is part of the `Compose` type, whereas in `<T>(x: () => T) => ...`, the `T` is part of the (anonymous) function call signature.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720954/typescript-how-to-create-a-generic-type-alias-for-a-generic-function) for more info