# TypeScript: Construct a typed interface based on a generic one

Tags: typescript, generics, types

TypeScript: Construct a typed interface based on a generic one, with the same methods but excluding the first parameter from all the functions.

Having a generic interface like:

```
interface GenericRepository {
  insertOne<E>(entity: Type<E>, body: E): Promise<string>;

  find<E>(entity: Type<E>, qm: Query<E>): Promise<E[]>;
}

interface Type<T> extends Function {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}

type Query<E> = {
  [K in keyof E]: E[K];
};

class User {
  firstName?: string;
}

class Company {
  name?: string;
}
```

I'd like to be able to dynamically "produce" specific interfaces/types like:

```
interface UserRepository {
  insertOne(body: User): Promise<string>;

  find(qm: Query<User>): Promise<User[]>;
}

interface CompanyRepository {
  insertOne(body: Company): Promise<string>;

  find(qm: Query<Company>): Promise<Company[]>;
}
```

Below is what I've till now but it is not working because the `entity` type is not properly inferred (for the specific interfaces):

```
type SpecificRepository<E> = {
  [K in keyof GenericRepository]: Fn<GenericRepository[K], E>;
};

type Fn<A extends (...args: any[]) => any, E> = (...a: Params<Parameters<A>>) => ReturnType<A>;

type Params<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer F, ...infer L] ? L : never;


const userRepository = {} as SpecificRepository<User>;
const companyRepository = {} as SpecificRepository<Company>;
```

If I do (for testing the "produced" types):

```
async function someMethod() {
  const foundUsers = await userRepository.find({});
}
```

Then `foundUsers` is of type `unknown[]` but it should be `User[]`.

How to make this properly?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/NVnvZN), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing without unrelated errors (what is `Type`? what is `Query`? what is `User`? what is `Company`?).  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: The main issue here is that you want the compiler to convert a generic function type into a nongeneric function type automatically, by specifying the generic type parameter somehow; this is not possible programmatically at the type level; you need to drop to value level, which means you need to write redundant code like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoqVaN).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720954/typescript-how-to-create-a-generic-type-alias-for-a-generic-function) for the general problem.  If this does not accurately describe/address your issue, let me know.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for the comments. I updated the comment to show the complete code. I know it is possible at the value level, but I wondered if/how it would be at the type level. Thanks again!

PD: so it is not possible because a typed (generic) parameter can not be obtained from a generic one (via types), right? Wondering if I can submit a request to the TS team for this feature.

Comment: Right, not possible now.  [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) and [ms/TS#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) and maybe even [ms/TS#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) are related issues but I don't know if any of them specifically address "I want to specify the generic type parameter in a generic function from the outside" this way.  You might want to open your own feature request, but don't be surprised if it's closed as a duplicate of something else.

Answer (score 0):

you're nearly there! To help TypeScript's inference mechanics, you should make the *interface* generic, rather than just its member function. This way you won't need to subclass either:

```js
interface GenericRepository<E> {
  insertOne(entity: Type<E>, body: E): Promise<string>;

  find(entity: Type<E>, qm: Query<E>): Promise<E[]>;
}

interface Type<T> extends Function {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}

type Query<E> = {
  [K in keyof E]: E[K];
};

class User {
  firstName?: string;
}

class Company {
  name?: string;
}

const userRepository = {} as GenericRepository<User>;
const companyRepository = {} as GenericRepository<Company>;

async function someMethod() {
  const foundUsers = await userRepository.find({});
}
```

Comment: that won't work because `find` and `insertOne` would still need the `entity` parameter (that is the one I want to remove). Please notice that the main point is: `GenericRepository` interface does already exists, and I want to automatically get a typed (via types/interfaces) repository interface from it but excluding the entity parameter from the methods. Thanks.