# Enforce 'typeof BaseClass' when base class is generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a generic abstract base class and a set of classes that extend the base and provide the generic param.

```
abstract class BaseClass<T> {
  constructor(protected container: T[]) { }
  static someStaticFunc(): string {
    return 'I\'m the BaseClass';
  }
  getElement(i: number): T {
    return this.container[i]
  }
}

class ConcreteClass1 extends BaseClass<number> {
  static someStaticFunc(): string {
    return 'I\'m ConcreteClass1'
  }

  addNumber(element: number) {
    this.container.push(element);
  }
}

class ConcreteClass2 extends BaseClass<string> {
  static someStaticFunc(): string {
    return 'I\'m ConcreteClass2'
  }

  addStringTwice(element: string) {
    this.container.push(element);
    this.container.push(element);
  }
}

class ConcreteClass3 extends BaseClass<boolean> {
    // Doesn't add anything
}
```

I define an interface structure where each value must be a `typeof BaseClass`

```
interface SetOfBaseClasses {
  Class1: typeof BaseClass,
  Class2: typeof BaseClass,
  Class3: typeof BaseClass
};
```

I want to create an object of that interface type, and assign the concrete classes to it. And then call each of the static functions on the class and get the expected results at the bottom.

```
const classes: SetOfBaseClasses = {
  Class1: ConcreteClass1,
  Class2: ConcreteClass2,
  Class3: ConcreteClass3
}

console.log(classes.Class1.someStaticFunc());
console.log(classes.Class2.someStaticFunc());
console.log(classes.Class3.someStaticFunc());

// Expected output:
// I'm ConcreteClass1
// I'm ConcreteClass2
// I'm the BaseClass
```

However, TypeScript does not see `ConcreteClass1`, `ConcreteClass2` or `ConcreteClass3` as compatible with `typeof BaseClass`. I figure this is because of the generic involved with BaseClass. So I also tried:

```
interface SetOfBaseClasses {
  Class1: typeof BaseClass<unknown>,
  Class2: typeof BaseClass<unknown>,
  Class3: typeof BaseClass<unknown>
};
```

and even more precisely:

```
interface SetOfBaseClasses {
  Class1: typeof BaseClass<number>,
  Class2: typeof BaseClass<string>,
  Class3: typeof BaseClass<boolean>
};
```

In either case, TypeScript does not seem to allow a generic parameter after `typeof Class`

I get two errors for each line in the interface that are something like this:

```
Call signature, which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.(7020)
Type parameter name cannot be 'number'.(2368)
```

Is there anyway to do this type of thing with TypeScript? Everything seems to be fine  with this approach until you involve generics.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYVXQB4AVAPgQG8AoBJAewDtIoBXeeqACgAcp6IOeDgAmDRhGABLRjigAuBCQDaAXQCUVBAF9aCSMAhTY%20%20gFscAZUlHYAMVaNYXdYpYyA5lT10oOCKxQjAgA5ACSADohZggQABY4WLgEaGAhANx6unQe-gCiyDgWElxSioysZiByrkredL7%20gcHxUmAAdLBMkjJyylKqWdS61CipCHhMsH6CKegAjAg4AB6CjCIY2GD4hGBEFVVyFDR0BramFtaGxg5OLm7QnvUNM82hkdETUzM7qfMhQz0wBEIgAcpVqtwcIVihByhCas86K0Ol0JNJZFB2jxWGA4lxoUUcBJ1Jk6LoRmN0F8nD85mAAExLVbEjZJbb0ojuRgeY56M7GC5WGw3RzOWrcrwnF5NILvKIxSa0-y-dAMgHk6hAkHWKCeEgAd2MOAJMOJcP0jx5mmlyLibU63QxcmxuPxhNhpJ8sXtqKdvSxOLxpqJJLJOmGWqpGCV0xV9IAzMy1mytqq9iB6PRCsBGHyGggAPSFhAAEXoODAjBCiGBYlzAE9WjzI9QZIIoAAzOCJSz%20ADynbT9Mrz3p80UEAbPBw9E77PT%20wRUDIABo9PSGZPp7P58Pdlyrbz13RE9uZ3OF5zM9mcLmyMNMtRO2KjEwEGYMS5nmjIEhdpWih9hAg77qko4ALxIhMuwTjScazLBJ4NJuiixnSuwMshp67AmaHfPGuGAnQv63u0yD0B4XDRpW7Tju0YDmMK1z2GKLheiRTCMYU5GUdRAEdJuDFMVcti3OKHHiNxOC8VRNGCbhwmXCKrF3OoXp6MWCB5MsM7CGI9CsBAOJwppJZhJ86GEX8ZkIBZioEYhqQMrZ9k%20okYHoMMQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `typeof BaseClass` is more or less equivalent to this:

```
type TypeofBaseClass =
  (abstract new <T>(container: T[]) => BaseClass<T>) &
  { someStaticFunc(): string };

const testTypeofBaseClass: TypeofBaseClass = BaseClass;
```

Note that `TypeofBaseClass` is not itself [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) (there is no type parameter on it); rather, it has an [`abstract` construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures) which is generic.  This is much like a generic function in that the generic type parameter is specified when you *call* it, not in the declaration itself.  A value of `typeof BaseClass` (or rather, a concrete generic subclass of it like `class ConcreteSubclass<T> extends BaseClass<T>`) can construct a `BaseClass<T>` for any `T` that the person who writes `new ConcreteSubclass` wants.  It could be a `BaseClass<string>` or a `BaseClass<number>` or anything else.

That's not the type you want.

---

Instead, the type you want here is more like this:

```
type TypeofConcreteClass<T> =
  (new (container: T[]) => BaseClass<T>) &
  { someStaticFunc(): string; };
```

This is a concrete constructor so the `abstract` is removed.  But more importantly, the scope of the generic type parameter `T` has been moved.  You want to be able to specify `TypeofConcreteClass<number>` which can only construct `BaseClass<number>` instances and not anything else.  The person who writes `new ConcreteClass1` will never be able to get a `BaseClass<string>` out.

---

It is not currently possible to automatically convert `typeof BaseClass` into `TypeofConcreteClass<T>` without jumping though ugly hoops.  The language does not really have a way of representing the relationship between them programmatically.  See ["TypeScript how to create a generic type alias for a generic function?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720954/typescript-how-to-create-a-generic-type-alias-for-a-generic-function) and its answer for more information.

For the above, I'd recommend just using a manually written `TypeofConcreteClass<T>` definition.  Or you could get part of the way there by doing something like

```
type TypeofConcreteClass<T> =
  Pick<typeof BaseClass, keyof typeof BaseClass> &
  (new (container: T[]) => BaseClass<T>);
```

which programmatically grabs all the `static` properties/methods of `BaseClass` while manually writing out the construct signature.

---

Let's verify that this works how you want:

```
interface SetOfBaseClasses {
  Class1: TypeofConcreteClass<number>,
  Class2: TypeofConcreteClass<string>,
  Class3: TypeofConcreteClass<boolean>
};

function main() {
  const classes: SetOfBaseClasses = {
    Class1: ConcreteClass1,
    Class2: ConcreteClass2,
    Class3: ConcreteClass3
  }

  console.log(classes.Class1.someStaticFunc());
  console.log(classes.Class2.someStaticFunc());
  console.log(classes.Class3.someStaticFunc());

  console.log(new classes.Class1([1, 2, 3]).getElement(2).toFixed(3)) // "3.000"
  console.log(new classes.Class2(["a", "b", "c"]).getElement(2).toUpperCase()) // "C"

}
```

That compiles with no error and works as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYVXQB4AVAPgQG8AoBJAewDtIoBXeeqACgAcp6IOeDgAmDRhGABLRjigAuBCQDaAXQCUVBAF9aCSMAhTY++gFscAZUlHYAMVaNYXdYpYyA5lT10oOCKxQjAgA5ACSADohZggQABY4WLgEaGAhANx6unQe-gCiyDgWElxSioysZiByrkredL7+gcHxUmAAdLBMkjJyylKqWdS61BAAnjyJJBM49ABm2GD4hBgAvHpcoCxwiLIA7gikZFxdEtKyCkpqmqsUi8upR5oAZHqUphbWhsYOTi5u0E8Oky1FOkFiOEg00m83uKXQimhswWyRWCFWSSW8LAIIA9AAqcaTJQzeZ4JiwPyCbFHdF6AAKxgA1kQicjMQ90AAaBBMnBjeaxUlzDnYiivOhcfYIE7dc5yRHXdF3VGPcjqdL43HUUYzEkwubkpxUzlgWnrSXS2VnXqXFQaZWilZPBASrRgcxWGw-RzOWruRgedLAnUoVIII2U-ymgCMCBwAA9BIwRBg4c6KlU5BQaHQDLYPl7vvZff99IDA-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)

Comment: thanks! This is pretty much exactly what I'm trying to do. One other thing would maybe be how do I best represent `SetOfBaseClasses` where I don't care about the type passed in as the generic param (in this part of the code at least). I'm used to using `unknown` as the generic param in that case, but it does not work here. `any` seems to work though, but I'm trying to avoid that when possible.  Perhaps here it's not really an issue.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have direct support for *existentially quantified generic types* (see [ms/TS#14466](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466)) so there's no simple type-safe way to say "a `TypeofConcreteClass<T>` for *some* `T` I don't care about". You can use `any` for simplicity and lose some type safety, or you could use helper functions to infer `T` so that you don't have to manually specify it. Existentials are often  unnecessary, though; what good is "a concrete subclass whose parameter I don't know" to you?  I would go on but this is out of scope for a comment chain.

Comment: Got it. In this case I'm building a framework that really just cares that those static methods exist and return strings exist on the Class type. `T` in this case could be infinitely arbitrary, so inferring T for all possible T is impossible. The type specified in the generic is more of an internal concern for the Class implementation, and specifies the type of data the component expects to received from an external data source. Obviously not clear at all from my contrived/obscure example. But thanks for the detailed explanation and advice!

Comment: Oh, then maybe you just want `{ someStaticFunc(): string; }` (or the equivalent) and not worry about the constructor/generic part at all.  Any object that has the right method will be allowed, including all those subclass constructors.  Good luck!