# Typescript: inject type in generic function while extracting its parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

I have a quite challenging issue.
Let's say i have a function that i cannot change since it's from a library

```js
function foo<T>(arg: T, n: number): any
```

so if i call `foo` with boolean type the compiler expects `arg` to be a `boolean`

```js
foo<boolean>(true, 1) //
```

Now, if i extract the parameters

```js
Parameters<typeof foo>
```

i get

```js
[T, number]
```

Is there a way to obtain the following type

```js
[boolean, number]
```

instead of

```
[T, number]
```

just by using `Parameters` utility type and the `foo` function so that i can inject the `boolean` data type as type for the first parameter?

Is it possible without changing the signature of the `foo` function?

I tried the following with no success:

```js
Parameters<typeof foo<boolean>>
Parameters<typeof foo><boolean>
```

the compiler says that the syntax is wrong.

I'm looking for a way that allows me to do this regardless of the parameter position in the parameters array

Comment: Calling the function once with the generic parameter set to `boolean` doesn't change the fact that the function is still defined in terms of `T`, not `boolean`.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYJXdw) work for you?

Comment: "i get `[T, number]`" Hmm, no you don't. [You get](https://tsplay.dev/Wvp4BN) `[unknown, number]`.  Could you edit the question to be more accurate?  But: there's no way to do what you want programmatically purely at the type level.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720954/typescript-how-to-create-a-generic-type-alias-for-a-generic-function) of which this is probably a duplicate.

Comment: @aleksxor so you're just replacing `unknown` with `boolean`, but there's no guarantee that the function won't have a non-generic `unknown` parameter.  Side note: you can do that replacement as a mapped type instead of as a recursive conditional; mapped types are preferably because they don't contribute to recursion depth which have shallow limits in TS.  See [this](https://tsplay.dev/W44kAW) for what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for great advice about mapped types. Looks like I overthought my type.