# Getting parameter type from overloaded generic function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have some third party code that looks something like this. (this is a simplified version)

```js
export declare function baz<T extends number>(  param1: T): void
export declare function baz<T extends string>(  param1: T): void
```

With that code you can do this.

```js
baz(1)
baz('2')
```

I want to extend the baz function and use the type of the param of the original baz

```js
function baz2(p: Parameters<typeof baz>[0]) {
  // ... some code
  baz(p)
}
```

This works

```js
baz2('1')
```

This wont work

```js
baz2(1)
```

I tried to do something like this but you can't pas generics in typeof

```js
function baz2<T>(p: Parameters<(typeof baz)<T>[0]) {
  baz(p)
}
```

Is there a way to extend the third party function and use all of the parameter types from the third party declaration?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724646/3388225) answer your question?