# Create function overload defined on type

Tags: typescript

How can I use an overloaded function defined on a type like so:

```
function myFunction<T, U extends keyof T>(keys: U[]): Pick<T, U>
function myFunction<T, TSelected = unknown>(funcArg: (state: T) => TSelected): TSelected;

type HoneyState<T> = {
  getValue: myFunction<T>
}
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFzXmAPAFQBpEBVRAUwA8pywATAZ0QGtzU5hF8A+ACldQMAXKQDaAXQCUIgAowIzAsRLcAUKEiwEKDFi14iXAMrkANuWjk6iALyJwzMHADuYPhogBBAE4BzEbwMUACGNCL4krbcxmYWNHTSMeaWdADcqqpQqAAO5IgAEghsRiE0BNF2AN6qiIi+5FAAasGmIOQiaJiaOOWqAL4ZQA)

Doing this gives me the error:

> 'myFunction' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof myFunction'?

What would be the correct way to go about using overloaded functions on types? Pulling them into one doesn't work because the return types are different

Comment: There error message there seems pretty clear, when you do what it says you should do, does it do what you want it to do?

Comment: @AlexWayne How do I use a function on a type like above without doing it directly on the type? If I do it directly on the type, it doesn't allow for overloading :)

Comment: `typeof myFunction` is not the correct solution here

Comment: That playground link gives you two errors; the first is that your overloaded function has no implementation.  If that is not what you're asking about, could you fix it so that the code here is a [mcve]?  This question also seems to have little to do with overloads, and more to do with the difference between generic functions and generic types, as demonstrated in [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720954/typescript-how-to-create-a-generic-type-alias-for-a-generic-function).  You can't easily get the compiler to change the scope of a generic type parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since typescript currently doesn't support higher kinded types ([microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)), your code will not work as you intend. However, there is a workaround in your use case here. You could create a type that has the same name as your function above, and use it for your desired typing purposes. See code below:

```
interface myFunction<T> {
    <U extends keyof T>(keys: U[]): Pick<T, U>;
    <TSelected = unknown>(funcArg: (state: T) => TSelected): TSelected;
}

type HoneyState<T> = {
  getValue: myFunction<T>
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&install-plugin=typescript-playground-link-shortener#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsBPAMTU11QB4AVAGngFV4QAPDEVYAZ3gGsQRHIng0AfAAoBRbgC4mAbQC6ASnkAFLGD60GjMQChQkWAhTpseQqXKXq9UQGUQEcB2DwAvPDR9UOAHdUSXMwAEEYAHN5CW4MKA55GhUvMScXNxBgNXTXTCyAbgMDLFQOGEQoMARiMgtKWjSAbwN4NvgqZjYOLl5pYVFJaTlFVQ0tHQd9IvaOmmc89y8fVD9A4IlQiOj4WPjE0RTPNPmM-OykhczgIoBfYowiAAcEAAk8QUd9kEbllrbIiAMAA1KAQZAgeS1WwNcQGe5AA)

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for thank you! Unfortunate that there has to be a workaround for something like this because overloading is supported. Appreciate it!