# JSDoc assign generic type to a value

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I have a project where I'm using JSDoc to annotate types and typescript definition files to create those types more comfortably.
I am porting some generic types from JSDoc to typescript, because it is easier to write.
I found that I can not assign a generic type directly to a variable because it says that I must provide the type arguments. So, if I try to do this:

```js
/*
 * @type {import('./api').WithDb}
 */
const withDb = handler => async args => {
```

It fails because WithDb requires two arguments, but this is exactly what I want, to say that this is a generic function.
JSDoc allows you to define generic types using the `@template` syntax so I can re-annotate the function like this:

```js
 /*
 * @template T
 * @template K
 * @type {import('./api').WithDb<T,K>}
 */
const withDb = handler => async args => {
```

OR

```js
 /*
 * @template T,K
 * @type {import('./api').WithDb<T,K>}
 */
const withDb = handler => async args => {
```

But it is a lot of boilerplate that I would like to avoid. Is it any other way to bind the types other than `@type` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript how to create a generic type alias for a generic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720954/typescript-how-to-create-a-generic-type-alias-for-a-generic-function) You should define `WithDb` as a generic function, rather than a generic type (`export type WithDb = <T, K>(params) => ReturnType` rather than `export type WithDb<T, K> = (params) => ReturnType`)

Comment: That works fine for the JSDoc side, so on that regard, it is fantastic. However, I can no longer use that type as a generic on any definition file because it is no longer generic.

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck using `@type` I'm afraid. But you can *sort of* clean it up by sweeping the boilerplate under the rug:

1. Somewhere near the top of your file you can define a `@typedef` which will be an alias:

```js
/**
* @template T,K
* @typedef {import('./api').WithDb<T,K>} WithDb
*/
```

2. Then your implementation can use your newly aliased type:

```
/** @type {WithDb} */
const withDb = handler => async args => {
```

A bit clunky especially since you'll likely have `WithDb` in the typings file. but if you are using that type in a lot of places, then this will save you some characters. JSDoc covers a wide range of use cases, but it will always be pretty verbose.

Comment: When I try this I still need to provide the @template annotations where the type is used as well.