# How to bind a parameter to a generic function

Tags: typescript

I have a generic function `retrieve`:

```js
function retrieve<T>(endpoint: string, id: string, /* etc */): T {}
```

I'd like to define a function, e.g `retrieveUser`, that would bind the first parameter and also specify `T`.

I tried using `Function.prototype.bind()`:

```js
const retrieveUser = retrieve.bind(/* this */ undefined, "/user");
```

But this prevent me from specifying `T`.

I then tried using rest parameters:

```js
type User = { username: string, /* etc */ };
const retrieveUser = (...args) => retrieve<User>("/user", ...args);
```

Which does exactly what I want but Typescript complains:

- `error TS7019: Rest parameter 'args' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.`
- `error TS2556: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.`

Is it possible to make Typescript infer `args` types from the `retrieve` function ?
Is there a better way to achieve my goal ?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVgr5m) work for you?  TS doesn't really have the ability to represent higher order function type manipulation well, so you'd probably need a type assertion or redundant annotation somewhere no matter what you do.  If that is acceptable I can write up an answer; if not maybe someone else will have a suggestion?

Comment: @jcalz I hadn't thought about casting the function itself ! I'll accept your answer when you post one. Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz However, this falls apart when a generic type is used for arguments only. I'll have to find a workaround for those edge cases.

Comment: Yeah, the type manipulation you want is not supported by the language, so you will be forced to jump through some conceptually unnecessary hoops.  There are ways to drag the compiler through operations that might give you what you want but they will be worse than type assertions… like https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724646/2887218

Comment: Or, well, maybe it's not worse?  But it's crazy.  See [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NBeYbw).  If you want that I can write it up but it is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: You weren't lying, it looks more like magic than typescript. I'll stick to your original solution and just explicitly write argument types where needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript unfortunately doesn't directly support the kind of higher-order generic function type manipulation you'd like to do here.  Ideally there would be a way to say "specify `T` in `typeof retrieve` with `User`", and then you'd just do that before binding the parameter.  But there isn't any reasonable way of doing this.  Perhaps if the language supported *higher-kinded types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) or *generic values* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) there'd be a way to do this cleanly.

---

The least ad-hoc workaround is to write out the type "specify `T` in `typeof retrieve` with `User`" explicitly, [annotate a variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) as that type and assign `retrieve` to it:

```
const userRetrieve: (endpoint: string, id: string, /* etc */) => User = retrieve; // okay
```

The compiler was happy with that, meaning that even though there's no easy way to programmatically specify `T` with `User` in the type system, it does understand that `retrieve` is assignable to the type you'd get if you could.  And that means there's type safety here; if you got the type wrong (say `(endpoint: number, id: string) => User`) you'd get a compiler error.

Anyway, now you can bind a parameter to `userRetrieve`:

```
const retrieveUser = userRetrieve.bind(undefined, "/user");
// const retrieveUser: (id: string) => User
```

---

If the parameters of `retrieve` are not generic, you can use [the `Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) to get the list of parameter types and save you some keystrokes:

```
const userRetrieve: (...args: Parameters<typeof retrieve>) => User = retrieve; // okay
const retrieveUser = userRetrieve.bind(undefined, "/user");
// const retrieveUser: (id: string) => User
```

And in either case if you don't care as much about type safety as expedience, you can replace the type-annotated variable with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const retrieveUser =
  (retrieve as (...args: Parameters<typeof retrieve>) => User).
    bind(undefined, "/user");
```

which is about a short as I can make it.

---

If the parameters do depend on the generic type parameter, though, `Parameters<T>` will lose track of any type parameter:

```
declare function retrieve<T>(endpoint: string, id: string, somethingGenric: T): T;

const retrieveUser =
    (retrieve as (...args: Parameters<typeof retrieve>) => User).
        bind(undefined, "/user");
// const retrieveUser: (id: string, somethingGenric: unknown) => User
```

Oops, that's `unknown` and not `User`.  For this we have to write out the parameters ourselves and plug in the type parameter stuff properly:

```
const retrieveUser =
    (retrieve as (endpoint: string, id: string, somethingGenric: User) => User).
        bind(undefined, "/user");
// const retrieveUser: (id: string, somethingGenric: User) => User
```

There *are* ways to abuse the limited support for [higher order generic function inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) to get the compiler to plug in `T` for you, but it's practically voodoo magic. I won't explain it because I already did so in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724646/2887218) and I don't know if I could even explain it in a way that made sense to people.  Here it is though:

```
class GenTypeMaker<T> {
    getGenType!: <A extends any[], R>(cb: (...a: A) => R) => () => (...a: A) => R;
    genType = this.getGenType(null! as typeof retrieve)<T>()
}
type Retrieve<T> = GenTypeMaker<T>['genType']
// type Retrieve<T> = (endpoint: string, id: string, somethingGenric: T) => T
```

You see that the compiler has deduced the type for `Retrieve<T>` to be the same as the function type of `retrieve` when you specify `T`.  So `Retrieve<User>` is the type you want:

```
const retrieveUser =
    (retrieve as Retrieve<User>).
        bind(/*this*/ undefined, "/user");
// const retrieveUser: (id: string, somethingGenric: User) => User
```

Isn't that cool?  But not anything I'd recommend.  In cases like this you should just write the type out yourself and annotate or assert that `retrieve` can be used as that type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5YyDeAoJukBMJ4AbEAJ2QDMBXYeAFwEsB7YJC+sxiANwgB4AKgD4AFBGD4YzRsHoAuJFE6yA5gBokjfIuVdgGpAHoAVEgj14SE0YCUiwQG4sOPPQCeMZAFUoEMkgAvEgYSNR+ZKCQuioGmqbmltZGSAC+zq648KzKYREAShZcvBCK4pLSsgpKsYbaMfqGCRZWNrZBwki+-kHsRdx8jsYpzADWIO6ZSNnAuRzFfN0BweH+hSolAHQARrL4orSElLIQ+JoAREarZOe2znjD0zn0fRuLEWX1NY3tgZ1LLlSLii0DgiCQggA7swQlNCCRyFRaAwWGx5gMBCJylIZHIGmpNF89ATjGYWsl7BCMg8PF4uhFeqFriD8XFSYlWil0i4HjNctd1gtSkhRJsxeRVFBFAAFcjgCz+KD8WkQZiUV5C4S-f4M4LokpDIwjcaTXnPDUYpa9AX9La7SQHSQQY7oM5IS7XW73PBGp6zF7697+T46b5qbX0-wuLBArAg2AIZCCAAWFEwcKIpAoSBodCYrAtJSEYgkOKqrLqoeJbOaSTaDmpbk8Pl1ITy-hZYZrZLrXMbWXNgYgVsCUweoiHSBAUBFYs2EqlSFlZHl9EVyubasLfC1HUjZFsmzHDzw9v2h2dJzdHoiXujsfjYOQADFmNQAtgeXh4VmkXnUdumIlhUuLVNWlYVpoUDMJA9DJmoADiEhcPADiUk4UwqvujLtpE8qQey5I2Gk-Z+nMtpBssx64BOFHINOs7imQkoynKsHriqW5Drufz7oe1EnmejpHFeFxXLedxTL6fIBnRSwhgR0GwfBBhIcAKGKLQozAMwkLABGVqALwbgBEe4C0aPomSDPowfCwl+uA-oiObIvmaJ0cW2KVHiXYQT5UEwRYKmqGpGkQuh3q4FhI5tsy+F+YRvYkfZZGyW8w66gJtFpVOM6eaBBFErU-nKYhyGMKhfF7ks-EnrVSBCReLqnGJnqSQ80mDnJHwioVjTFYFpXqeVijVVVERmcC8oJuCADKjAAB52RmCLZrmKIFkOHmll5YFFVoVZ7UpA2qWVFWCOFmHNthwRMhEnbgfEPacklUwIlAM5qYIzYALIgKM-jFrCdVIKoFifc2ACEij8AAguY81rpIM4gMA7gANoALqaPkYjwNsZRziAigwxG+QRqI5OE8TpMRSeoPAF9dLBHBjBQJsoP0ODXiiMA1DEMQEM5UgnHqkOtgebYUxAjSV2ChigPBFzEC-f9ZDFmjADk9OMxAGsY1JKRYXLRYiL0eXlvFvUkkdLMnUNZ0RoI0Zmv6gEjplk4McbfD8EsWpHsDDxCaYLNQMRjWie64n+He7UpDJbvdaIVtsjbQUhcNlW8QCMZAA)

Answer (score -1):

it's now merged in main, not implemented yet is last release ;).

=> https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31302240)