# TypeScript: Extract parameters from generic function type as a separate type

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following type setup coming from a library (the whole [code snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM4Fk5igXigbwFgAoKKZCYACwHsATARgC4CSyywEaxmpVgEASwB2AcwA0bKAF9JpcpVp0ATCyLyOXHi2EBXZACMICOeyiduqvgJESp0kg+KhIUdIvqpcUANYQQNABmsIgoGFgA3CQu0ACKusYg3gA8ANJQEAAewBDCdF7u1J4AfAAUFEV0LKni5qFoLPBIaJhgANqpALoAlLjFUABuNIJ0UcQAxjTC-FAAjgkIICzxid7lHnS1YPWovTj96mQA9Ed8NBRQADY0ooLjUpPTNJcQAHTXoqUABgAk+BVKaRQFh-ABSAGUAPIAOVe-CEYkEgRApW2zV20i+3TG0jG80SpQARAD6AxCbV8OYtLxCQxlABmAAshJk2JIJBOUBiVzg4x8tigolyxjuUDgeSgwhowAywkCNAQ4wFJLoAFoLGAvNtBAjRByAFRc8DQQReNoqlh+ALBJphVpbHZqKSabi8eG2HFQAA+rA0VNdOn0RgQYzMGqs7rEOM6+qO0WNUAAotkkONgCtFra0N4s5RjKhkhmQMV2RMpjMcvwGGtXrW0WEWMmBLz0wsQFndn1fWRHqhnm8Pt8wVDYZHbsjUTtupi2cQnJXgAwiSqyRT-dooAwtlorITUHRAqgWdJZxzTlQ4ANoMAaFBdKhoPjFoNEII4AYXlzb1lm2m6s08wQLwhWEEV7mITk0gybJcnyXx-CCEJ0Vafo8HNDZqgddFGh2VoOk6ToSBeGVZmWNsxm5JtU1bRIOwAdUEagADVECgn9YIKDZUFQpCUEAgsYkQ2Y0mKEsy2mGUF2UFJ0nYvJOMqbjSlrV56waJMUxbIt6MYqgWIQES9gOB5y37d4biHfAIRhOEbERCc1IxLEcTPPhaAAdy8YwuAQVypOXDZVwIddeC3ddd33Q9j1nfziQ2ZRyWCjVQu3SwWD3A8j1ZCIgA)):

```
type ParamsMap = {
  method1: {
    prop1: string,
  },
  method2: {
    prop1: number,
    prop2: string,
  }
}
type Methods = keyof ParamsMap;
type Query = <K extends Methods>(method: K, params: ParamsMap[K]) => void;
```

There is a library implementation with this type, a typical call pattern:

```
const query: Query = (method, params) => {
  //some logic
  console.log(`${method} : ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
};
query("method1", { prop1: "1234" });
```

I would like to extract parameters from query so I can call a function of **Query** type under the hood and perform extra processing (return type doesn't matter in this case).

I tried to apply **Parameters** utility class but the resulting type lacks method-prop constraint:

```
/* type is [method: keyof ParamsMap, params: {
    prop1: string;
} | {
    prop1: number;
    prop2: string;
}]*/
type ExtractQueryParams = Parameters<Query>
const test1 = (...params: ExtractQueryParams) => {
  console.log(`${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
}
//possible to call method1 with method2 props
test1("method1", { prop1: 1, prop2: "sdfs" });
```

The only way I've come up with is to define extra variable of type **Query** and to pass a generic to it inside *typeof* clause:

```
let q: Query;
// <K extends keyof ParamsMap> = [method: K, params: ParamsMap[K]]
type ExtractQueryParamsWithVar<K extends Methods> = Parameters<typeof q<K>>
const test2 = <K extends Methods>(...params: ExtractQueryParamsWithVar<K>) => {
  console.log(`${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
}
// now shows error
test2("method1", { prop1: 1, prop2: "sdfs" });
```

Is there a better way to extract these parameters with generic constraint being preserved?

Comment: No, there's no better way.  [You can't use instantiation expressions directly at the type level](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607#issuecomment-1058144708).  I mean, [this is strictly better than it was before TS4.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720954/typescript-how-to-create-a-generic-type-alias-for-a-generic-function), but you still need to have (or pretend to have) a variable of the generic function type in question.  Does this fully address your question and is worthy of an answer writeup? Or am I missing something about your issue?

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for answering and providing the links. I think your comment fully covers the issue for me. Is it better to post a self-answer in this case?

Comment: If you want to write up your own answer, that's absolutely fine with me.  If you don't then I will probably write one up but not right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now, you can't extract paramteters directly. But it's possible to **introduce/use an existing variable** with the generic function type and utilize an *instantiation expression* as described by [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72816670/typescript-extract-parameters-from-generic-function-type-as-a-separate-type?noredirect=1#comment128615832_72816670).

So basically, the `ExtractQueryParamsWithVar` type from the question is a way to solve it (you still have to copy the generic constraint itself, though compiler shows an error if they are omitted, obviously):

```
let q: Query;
// <K extends keyof ParamsMap> = [method: K, params: ParamsMap[K]]
type ExtractQueryParamsWithVar<K extends Methods> = Parameters<typeof q<K>>
```

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM4Fk5igXigbwFgAoKKZCYACwHsATARgC4CSyywEaxmpVgEASwB2AcwA0bKAF9JpcpVp0ATCyLyOXHi2EBXZACMICOeyiduqvgJESp0kg+KhIUdIvqpcUANYQQNABmsIgoGFgA3CQu0ACKusYg3gA8ANJQEAAewBDCdF7u1J4AfAAUFEV0LKni5qFoLPBIaJhgANqpALoAlLjFUABuNIJ0UcQkAPQTUGkZ2bn5vv5BIc3hYP14bRVK1bVg9aiNh60dnZ0kADaUUACOLPGJYzFQAKLZSADGwI8IIE1hADqgmoADVELMsjk8gUPPlNqsUJRjKhkjEVrc0sViiRPjRhPwoDl+MoUukoQtYZVUGUAHT0g5rFjvARwb6-f6HYFgiGpYq9HD9dRkPEEmjXWmXGiiUoAAwAJPgAFIAZQA8gA5Wn8IRiQSBEClRlhbrSWXdMZOKZ8WgAdy8xi4CEm02JwGUpQARDt6AxPbV8OYtLwGPstFZPag6IFUJ6ZBbohASV6fSp-QQg9wQ2HLCxI9HY-GIkA)