# What is the difference, and is it possible to access a generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Imagine we have two types, that are similar, though not the same:

```ts
type First<G> = (arg: G) => G
type Second = <G>(arg: G) => G
```

Now obviously when talking about these two types, there are differences, I am wondering, if someone can explain, in detail, what those differences are, how do we refer to them, they are both "generics" but do they have a better, more distinct name, so that I can search for this, because I couldn't find anything.

From what I gather - `First` type requires us to specify a generic when defining a variable of said type whereas the `Second` type infers it from usage, depending on the line of code where we used it. Are there any other benefits? Or negatives? One particular issue I am having with the `Second` form is the fact that I cannot assert to `G`

I've also ran into an issue of following:

```ts
const myFunction: Second = (arg) => {
  let someValue = getExternalValue() // typeof someValue === unknown
  return someValue as G // this is an issue, I cannot access G
}
```

Now I know assertions are bad, and all that, but is there a way of writing this to access this generic `G` ? Obviously the example is not a real codebase code, just demonstrating a point.

Comment: Does this answer first your question? [TypeScript how to create a generic type alias for a generic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720954/typescript-how-to-create-a-generic-type-alias-for-a-generic-function)

Comment: The difference between `First` and `Second` is that `First` is a generic type that goes to a function and `Second` is a generic function. To access `G` in your example, add `<G,>` in front of the `(arg)` [What is the syntax for Typescript arrow functions with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308370/what-is-the-syntax-for-typescript-arrow-functions-with-generics)