# What is it called when a function has a late-binding generic type?

Tags: typescript, function, typescript-generics, terminology, late-binding

What is it called when a function has a late-bound Generic type (which is determined only when the function is called, not when it is defined).

It is shown as `LateT` in the code example below, and contrasted with the `EarlyT` early-bound case where the type of the function reference itself already has the typed constraint (and it's not late-bound when the function call is evaluated).

I am trying to find documentation for this style of function definition and to describe it as part of an API and I am struggling to reference the right part of the Typescript documentation without the correct distinguishing terms.

```js
type Op<EarlyT> = (item:EarlyT) => void

type LateOp = <LateT>(late:LateT) => void;
```

Comment: What you’re calling “late-bound” is just referred to as a “generic function” (or possibly “generic call signature”), while what you’re calling “early-bound” is referred to as a “generic type” (the function it refers to is not a generic function)

Comment: Although I've never heard it discussed this way, you might find it helpful to think of the `Op` type as analogous to a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) in the type system because it captures the generic at the time of creation and that becomes the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) for the parameter — in contrast to `LateOp`, which is analogous a normal function: the generic can be [inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) at the usage site instead.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75639030/what-is-it-called-when-a-function-has-a-late-binding-generic-type#comment133443409_75639030) FWIW: You can use `LateOp` the same way as `Op` by binding the generic parameter: https://tsplay.dev/mxj18w

Comment: If you look at [the TS handboc docs for generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types) they refer to something like `LateOp` as "describing a generic function" and to the `Op`-version of it as a "non-generic function signature that is a part of a generic type".  Does that count as official enough for your purposes? If so I will write this up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: `Op` is also called a type constructor, or a generic type alias to distinguish it from a generic interface

Comment: Thanks @jcalz @jsejcksn @geoffrey with `generic function` versus `generic type constructor for a function type` the official terminology gives me a good headstart. I was expecting something specifically about late-binding in the terminology as these are all quite self-similar phrases. It's crazy to think that `<Type>(arg: Type) => Type = identity` is actually practically the first example of generics of any kind in the handbook, and yet I was scrolling for pages and pages elsewhere and giving up on finding an example :) Probably I'll use late-binding as a descriptive term for lack of another.

Comment: @jsejcksn yes that scheme to narrow the binding of a function as a const is really neat!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're calling a "late-bound generic" is referred to in TypeScript as a generic *function* or *call signature*, while what you're calling an "early-bound generic" is referred to in TypeScript as a generic *type*.

The relevant documentation can be found in the [TypeScript Handbook section on generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types), where a type like `LateOp` "describes a generic function" while a type like `Op` is a "non-generic function signature that is a part of a generic type".

---

So in

```
type GenFunc = <T>(x: T) => void;
```

the `GenFunc` *type* is non-generic (it has no generic type parameter) but it refers to a generic *call signature* (it has a generic type parameter), while in:

```
type GenType<T> = (x: T) => void
```

the `GenType` *type* is generic (it has a generic type parameter) but it refers to a non-generic *call signature* (it has no generic type parameter itself, although the type parameter from the generic type is still in scope).

---

See [TypeScript how to create a generic type alias for a generic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62720954/2887218) for some more discussion about the relationship between generic functions and generic types.