# Generic factory of non-generic functions

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider the following snippet:

```js
const graphql = {
    query: function<A, B>(x: string, y: (a: A, b: B) => void) {
        return x;
    }
}

function makeOverride<Q, V>(queryName: string) {
  return (fn: Parameters<typeof graphql.query<Q, V>>[1]) => graphql.query<Q, V>(queryName, fn)
}

const bound = makeOverride<string, boolean>('some')
const bound2 = makeOverride<number, 'cow' | 'dog'>('some')

// this works fine
bound((x: string, y: boolean) => {})
bound2((x: number, y: 'cow' | 'dog') => {})
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get `makeOverride` to serve as a factory for functions with constrained parameters.

When dealing with an external library (`graphql` is a crude, simplfied version of an object coming from `msw` but with the exact same signature) what alternative approach, other than `Parameters` utility type, could I use to achieve the same result and ensure that any `fn` passed to `makeOverride<A, B>("")(fn)` follows the `(x: A, b: B) => void` constraint?

I'm sorry if the wording in my description is inaccurate, but Typescript at this level continues to be nothing short of wizardry to me :)

Comment: Which one of these two questions is your primary question?  [Please pick just one of them to ask here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/511366).

Comment: it's definitely the latter I'm more interested in!

Comment: Okay then please [edit] the question to remove the less interesting question (which can be asked in a separate post if you want).

Comment: Once you do [edit] the question; is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6GDrN) what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Edited, sorry not to follow the rules!
What I'm looking for is a generic (pun intended) approach to the problem - in the playground you've added included, function which is passed to `makeOverride` is hardoced (albeit with generic params) and so, if we change the implementation of `graphql.query` it won't work anymore and thus my attempt at using `Parameters`.

Comment: ① Maybe the question should mention that in some way? Right now it just says "follows the `(x: A, b: B) => void` constraint" but instead it should say something like "is the same type as the second parameter type of ..." and fill in "..." with whatever your actual source function is (you say `graphql.query` is not the actual source necessarily, or its implementation can change, so I'm not sure what you want it to be).  I'd also be interested in understanding how you'd implement `makeOverride` in a way that would work at runtime, if `graphql.query`'s signature isn't known enough to hardcode it.

Comment: ② If your source is just a function type you don't control then there is no approach meaningfully different from using `Parameters<F>`. You could write your own version of it tailored to grab the second parameter type, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3vDbN), but it's no different. I'm not sure why you're looking for an alternative approach; can you explain what's wrong with what you're doing now?  (Both of these ideally would be reflected in [edit]s to the questions as opposed to comments)

Comment: Thank you for replying. The only reason I'm looking for a different approach (I mentioned that in the unedited question) is because the snippet attached does not compile in TS < 4.7.4 https://tsplay.dev/WYQpvW and I honestly do not comprehend those errors. Any idea how to go about them? Is this maybe caused by two consecutive `>>`  being misintrpreted as `jsx` ?

Comment: So you were actually looking for the answer to the first question primarily? Then presumably you would have edited to ask that one instead of this one (and then follow-up later with the second one in a new post if the answer to the first one didn't resolve things.) The snippet doesn't compile pre-TS4.7 not because of `Parameters` but because you're using an [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) which wasn't introduced until TS4.7.

Comment: Maybe you should [edit] to: "I need to do X in the following version(s) of TypeScript, how can I do it"?

Comment: (see prev 2 comments).  Anyway, this is starting to look like you're asking a version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62720954/2887218). TS's support for higher order generics is fairly limited. You can't easily do what you want purely at the type level, but at least TS4.7 lets you instantiate a generic function's type args without calling it. Before TS4.7 you'd have to play dirty tricks to get the compiler to compute this for you, as shown in my answer to the linked q, and [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nn8daW). Does that count as an alternative approach?

Comment: thank you jcalz, this is the exact thread and the answer I've been looking for (and moreover it's also by you)!

Comment: Okay, great! I've forwarded this question to that one.